# Adding dots to an empty region of space

Tags: plotting, programming, map, plot-themes, dot

[image: a busy cat]

I want to add dots to the maze so far I know only how to get one dot on the maze. I don't know if there is way without using coordinates.

So it would look like this with the dots added

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [trelford.com](http://trelford.com/blog/image.axd?picture=maze_thumb.png))</sub>

Comment: This question seems to be too broad or unclear in isolation.  Please include the context necessary to make sense of the question.

Answer (score 11):

I feel this answer is as sensible as the question.

First, binarise the image:

```
m = Import["maz1.jpg"]
bin = Opening[ColorNegate@Binarize[m], 6]
```

[image: 1]

Find the biggest white space, and thin it into a skeleton

```
thin = Thinning[SelectComponents[bin, "Count", -1], Method -> "MedialAxis"]
```

[image: 2]

I used "MedialAxis" here to make it squarer, at the cost of extra bits hanging off.  But we'll trim those later.

Turn it into a graph:

```
g = MorphologicalGraph[thin, VertexSize -> 4, VertexStyle -> Yellow]
```

[image: 3]

Extract the coordinates of the vertices:

```
vertices = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates];
vrules = Sort[Rule @@@ Transpose[{VertexList[g], vertices}]];
```

Pick out the edges that don't have a vertex of degree 1:

```
bad = Pick[VertexList[g], VertexDegree[g], 1];
good = Select[EdgeList[g], ! MemberQ[bad, First@#] && ! MemberQ[bad, Last@#] &];
```

Calculate dots along each good edge at a vaguely even spacing:

```
dots = Union@Flatten[Module[{a = #1 /. vrules, b = #2 /. vrules, d},
      d = 1 + 1/10 Round[EuclideanDistance[a, b], 10];
      a + #/d (b - a) & /@ Range[0, d]] & @@@ good, 1];

Show[m, Graphics[{Yellow, Point /@ dots}]]
```

[image: 4]